# Obtener datos formulario - De un modal dentro de datatable con ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas noches tengo una tabla que recargo su información con AJAX. Dentro de esa tabla hay un botón para editar el cliente en el que se abre una ventana modal, dentro hay un formulario y quiero obtener los datos del que estoy editando.

```
window.onload = function() {
    actualizaTabla();
};
let listadoClientes = [];
function actualizaTabla(){
    var url = '/actualizar-tabla-clientes';
    $.ajax({
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: url,
        beforeSend: function(){
            
        },
        success: function (resultado){
            console.log(resultado);
            listadoClientes.length = 0;
            $('#elModal').empty();
            for(i=0;i<resultado.clientes.length;i++){
                listadoClientes.push(resultado.clientes[i]);
            }
            $('#clientes').DataTable({
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                pageLength: 30,
                processing: true,
                destroy: true,
                paging: true,
                searching: false,
                info: true,
                data: listadoClientes,
                order:[[0,'asc']],
                columns: [
                          ....
                          ....
                          { data: "email" },
                          { data: null, render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                            ....
                            return '<a href="#editCliente_'+ data.id +'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editCliente_'+ data.id +'" class="downFactura btn11">\
                                    <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>\
                                </a>\
                             ......
                            <div class="modal fade" id="editCliente_'+ data.id +'" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editCliente_'+ data.id +'Label" aria-hidden="true">\
                            ......
                            <div class="form-group form-group-default">\
                               <label for="nombre">Nombre<span style="color: red;">*</span></label>\
                               <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control pulsaInput" id="nombre" value="'+ data.nombre +'" required autocomplete="off">\
                            </div>\
                            .....
                            <a class="btn btn-primary crearCliente pruebaAct" id="actualizar_cliente">Actualizar cliente</a>\
                          }},
```

He comprimido un poco la información, pero veis como relleno la tabla y como dentro de ella hay un botón que abre un modal con los datos de la persona a la cual le hago clic.

Después con una función intento obtener los datos pero no hay manera.

```
$("body").on("click",".pruebaAct", this, function(){
  var nombre = $('#nombre').val();
  console.log(nombre);
});
```

Siempre me devuelve el primero, alguna sugerencia??